# Open and Dense Substack

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topos-theory, algebraic-stacks

I am looking for a definition of open and dense substack of a Deligne-Mumford stack $\mathcal X$.

I have looked at the one on [nlab - dense subtopos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+subtopos), but, as I don't know much about topos theory, I am wondering whether there is a definition which does not use the characterisation of DM-stacks as ringed topoi locally equivalent to the étale spectrum of a commutative ring.

Furthermore, is this notion stable under 2-pullback in the 2-category of stacks?